# Chrome SVG rendering artifacts

Tags: google-chrome, svg, path

I have a simple example of a Chrome SVG rendering issue. There are two overlapping triangles—but instead of being filled with a solid color, a gradient is added in Chrome:

https://jsfiddle.net/prozoroff/f97tjwcb/

```
<svg width="1000px" height="1000px">
  <path id='path' d="M100 100 L100 200 L200 100 M150 150 L200 200 L180 200"
   stroke="none" fill="rgba(50,50,50)"></path>
</svg>
```

Has anyone else come across this issue? It looks like a bug but maybe there are some ways to fix it in code?

Comment: That's a weird one, for sure.

Comment: The only things wrong with your code is that `rgba()` colors need an explicit fourth value for alpha, even if it's `1`, and `<path/>` elements are meant to be self-closing. But fixing those things doesn't make a difference. Definitely a bug.

Comment: It's probably a bug. You should report it to chrome

Comment: If you have reported it to Chrome, then please post a link to the bug report here (for the benefit of future readers).

Comment: nvm. I've reported it myself to Skia. It seems to be a bug with the GPU renderer. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/skia/issues/detail?id=8930

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around this issue is by moving the second move (`M`) slightly off the diagonal line.

```
 M150.2 150.2
```

```html
<svg width="1000px" height="1000px">
  <path id='path' d="M100 100 L100 200 L200 100 M150.2 150.2 L200 200 L180 200"
   stroke="none" fill="rgb(50,50,50)"></path>
</svg>
```